# How to apply function returning data.frames with factors to sequence

Tags: r, dataframe

How do I apply a function which returns a data.frame with factors to a sequence?

Example:

```
s <- factor(c(10, 20, 30))
t <- factor(c("a", "b", "a"))
v <- c(5, 6, 4)

df <- data.frame(s,t,v)
```

So the data.frame df is this:

```
   s t v
1 10 a 5
2 20 b 6
3 30 a 4
```

I also have a function which returns a data.frame:

```
simpleFunc2 <- function(df, x){
  tmp <- subset(df, df$s == x)
  return(tmp)
}
```

Now I have a sequence

```
x <- c(20, 30, 10, 30, 10)
```

and want to the result auf applying the function simpleFunc2 to this sequence.

I use sapply

```
sapply(x, function(x) simpleFunc2(df, x))
```

But I get

```
  [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]    
s factor,1 factor,1 factor,1 factor,1 factor,1
t factor,1 factor,1 factor,1 factor,1 factor,1
v 6        4        5        4        5
```

How do I get the right values of the factors back?

This example is simplified. So maybe there's a much simpler way to do it in this case.

Comment: Your function can just be written as `df[df$s == x,]` I don't even see a need for a function. And subset is notorious for scoping issues. (I see now that @BondedDust said this already)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try `lapply` instead with `do.call` as in:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(x, function(x) simpleFunc2(df=df, x)))
```

Comment: That looks good. Thank you. But I've got two questions: Why does lapply preserves the factors? And how are the row numbers created? I got    
        s t v
    2  20 b 6
    3  30 a 4
    31 10 a 5
    32 30 a 4
    5  10 a 5

Comment: Well `sapply` is a wrapper for `lapply`.  I rarely use `sapply` but I know it tries to simplify things.  It may be that when your function returns a data frame of different classes trying to `sapply` is trying to force things as a matrix or vector and then the classes get messed up.  Or maybe not.  Lesson is that `lapply` is more flexible as a list is returned and it isn't being coerced. As far as the rownames... Your function returns that already.  All my approach does is splice the whole shebang together.

Answer (score 5):

I see you have gotten an answer to your question, but I think your approach to selecting the superset from that dataframe was too involved. (And my apologies if that function was not representative. I'd like to offer a method of extraction that is faster than going through `subset`:

```
> df[ match(x, df$s), ]
     s t v
2   20 b 6
3   30 a 4
1   10 a 5
3.1 30 a 4
1.1 10 a 5
# Save results as from:
> do.call(rbind, lapply(x, function(x) simpleFunc2(df, x)) )
    s t v
2  20 b 6
3  30 a 4
31 10 a 5
32 30 a 4
5  10 a 5
```

Comment: S@DWin Agreed.  I hadn't really paid attention to what the users function was doing.  +1

Answer (score 0):

I do not quite understand the question, but both of the answers suggest that at least one simple method has been missing for all this time. It may often be convenient to type

```
merge(df,as.data.frame(x),by=1)
```

to get a sorted output with the right row/column names

```
   s t v
1 10 a 5
2 10 a 5
3 20 b 6
4 30 a 4
5 30 a 4
```

In terms of the performance, the proposed method can't compete with the method employing "match" but easily beats the method in the accepted answer.

```
   microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
 do.call=do.call(rbind, lapply(x, function(x) simpleFunc2(df, x))),
 match=df[match(x, df$s), ],
 merge= merge(df,as.data.frame(x),by=1))
```

.

```
Unit: microseconds
    expr      min       lq    median        uq      max neval
 do.call 2487.451 2523.033 2547.4060 2604.3850 9554.748   100
   match  175.117  180.197  183.2465  187.8135  248.835   100
   merge 1020.307 1035.062 1049.4835 1071.6575 8057.059   100
```